# jQuery-Timepicker-Addon slider doesn't work - interference with other PlugIns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I want to use the [jQuery-Timepicker-Addon](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) to display a datepicker with a timepicker as a slider. My problem is that the slider doesn't show. The code the PlugIn generates at the position where the slider should be looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-timepicker-div">
  <dl>
    <dt class="ui_tpicker_time_label">Time</dt>
    <dd class="ui_tpicker_time">00:00</dd>
    <dt class="ui_tpicker_hour_label">Hour</dt>
    <dd class="ui_tpicker_hour">
      <div class="ui_tpicker_hour_slider"></div>
    </dd>
    <dt class="ui_tpicker_minute_label">Minute</dt>
    <dd class="ui_tpicker_minute">
      <div class="ui_tpicker_minute_slider"></div>
    </dd>
    .
    .
    .
  </dl>
</div>
```

In the `ui_tpicker_hour_slider` and `ui_tpicker_minute_slider` divs is missing an a tag. In the official documentation this part looks like this:

```
<dd class="ui_tpicker_hour">
  <div class="ui_tpicker_hour_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false">
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a>
  </div>
</dd>
```

I have no Idea why the PlugIn doesn't include this markup.

My setup is:

- jQuery 1.11.1
- jQueryUI 1.10.3
- jQuery-Timepicker-Addon 1.4.5

I tried many different combinations of versions in my project, but I couldn't get it to work.

Are the any other jQuery PlugIns which may interfere with the jQuery-Timepicker-Addon? In my project I use many other jQuery PlugIns. I'm really helpless at this point.

Answer (score 0):

May be you create your own function named "slider" or has two functions named "slider" and second function override first function from timepicker?